# Converting digits into words(11=Eleven)

Tags: c#, winforms, numbers, digits

I need to convert digit into words. Example: when user inputs 10 , output should be displayed as ten . User can enter upto 999,999 . Whats the best way to get this output in C# windows forms.

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Nice discussion on this topic here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8f8fb535-2b3b-4f20-b55b-ea0331e40159/number-to-words?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: found out the answer. Thanks Guys